# What to do about sweet.js renaming top-level variables in Typescript output?

Tags: typescript, sweet.js

Typescript compiles

```
class ClassName { }
```

to

```
var ClassName = function () {
    function ClassName() {
    }
    return ClassName;
}();
```

I run that JS code through sweet.js, which *even when there are no macros defined*, produces something like this:

```
var ClassName$659 = function () {
    function ClassName$663() {
    }
    return ClassName$663;
}();
```

I understand that sweet.js would not rename the first occurrence of `ClassName` if the top-level `var` wasn't used, or if a different name was used for the constructor function, but it's the Typescript compiler that does those things, not me.

#### Why it's a problem

1. I can no longer use `ClassName` in HTML files. That's not something I want to do often, and I can of course always do without the capability, but I still miss having it.
2. The macros I want to use so-far don't require *any* hygienic renaming. Yet now it seems like I'll have to undo the renaming with my own script. Source maps won't help easily, since I already need a source map for the typescript --> javascript conversion.

#### My question

Is there a way to disable hygienic renaming in sweet.js?  Is there a better way to deal with this issue?

Comment: You can also compile with the _readableNames_ option which may clean up hygienic names whenever possible.

Comment: Thank you @AnthonyCalandra. I meant to include that I tried the readableNames flag.

Comment: Actually, @AnthonyCalandra, that worked. I must have done something wrong when I tried --readable-names before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the --readable-names flag with sjs, as @AnthonyCalandra suggested, resolved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to disable hygienic renaming in sweet.js?

No.

> Is there a better way to deal with this issue?

Not sure. As a hack you can post-process the file with a script that
searches for ClassName$xxx and then add

```
var ClassName = ClassName$xxx;
```

Comment: Surely this is a bug, right?  I mean, if I copy the "let macros" code verbatim from the documentation it renames the top-level function, making it uncallable (no function in existing code is going to know it has to add a dollar sign and some random number to the already known function name!)

Comment: also, for some reason it doesn't do this top-level renaming in the demo editor in the browser, only when running it under node. (surprise!)

Comment: @Michael This is just a hunch: Sweet.js switched to a new expansion algorithm. Maybe there is a difference between the old and the new one. Has the demo page switched yet? Note that the above answer is from before the switch.